# Supplying the list argument to .l in pmap() or pwalk()

Tags: r, purrr

I am unclear as to when arguments can be explicitly paired in pmap() and pwalk()'s `.l` argument. Sometimes these purrr functions only seem to work when the dataframe supplied to them has names that map directly to the expected arguments of the function named in `.f`. Other times a full dataframe can be supplied to pmap() and the variables can be pair mapped explicitly.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

set.seed(57)

ds_mt <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("model") %>% 
  mutate(am = factor(am, labels = c("auto", "manual"))) %>% 
  select(model, mpg, wt, cyl, am) %>% 
  sample_n(3)

foo <- function(model, am, mpg){
  print(
    paste("The", model, "has a", am, "transmission and gets", mpg, "mpgs.")
  )
}
```

Why do these code chunks work?

```
ds_mt %>% 
  select(model, am, mpg) %>% 
  pwalk(
  .l = .,
  .f = foo
)

# example with explicit pair mapping
ds_mt %>% 
  mutate(
    new_var = 
      pmap(
        .l = list(model=model, am=am, mpg=mpg),
        .f = foo
      )
  )
```

While these code chunks fail?

```
ds_mt %>% 
  pwalk(
  .l = list(model, am, mpg),
  .f = foo
)

ds_mt %>% 
  pwalk(
  .l = list(model=model, am=am, mpg=mpg),
  .f = foo
)
```

Comment: Your mutate example is not working for me

Comment: Got it: I think you have a typo and are missing `list()`

Comment: Thank you, I've corrected the typo. And appreciate your thorough response.

Comment: My pleasure. I hope it helped. I edited my answer by removing the (now useless) section about that typo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `pmap()` or `pwalk()`. It stems from some misunderstanding of how the pipe and the `mutate()` function work.

---

First, the pipe:

Unless otherwise specified by a dot, the pipe passes the left-hand side (LHS) as the first argument of the function on the right-hande side (RHS).

So this works:

```
ds_mt %>% 
  select(model, am, mpg) %>% 
  pwalk(
    .l = .,
    .f = foo
  )
```

because your list (= your data frame since a data frame is a list of vectors), which is the LHS of the pipe, is used as the first argument of `pwalk()` on the RHS.

In this case, you actually do not need the dot and you could have written it much more simply as:

```
ds_mt %>% 
  select(model, am, mpg) %>% 
  pwalk(foo)
```

On the other hand, when you try to run:

```
ds_mt %>% 
  pwalk(
    .l = list(model, am, mpg),
    .f = foo
  )
```

the connection between your LHS and your RHS do not follow the rules of the pipe, so R has no idea what `model` is since you don't have any object called `model`.

For this expression to work, you can write it, without the pipe, in this manner:

```
pwalk(
  .l = list(ds_mt$model, ds_mt$am, ds_mt$mpg),
  .f = foo
)
```

Or, if you want to use the pipe, you have to replace the LHS of the pipe by dots (since it is not passed as the first argument of the function on the RHS) where it is necessary for the code to work, but here, since you are passing the LHS inside nested functions, you also have to put the RHS between curly braces because R would otherwise pass the LHS as the first argument of the outer-most function of the RHS:

```
ds_mt %>% {
  pwalk(
    .l = list(.$model, .$am, .$mpg),
    .f = foo
  )
}
```

or, in a style a little more compact:

```
ds_mt %>% {pwalk(list(.$model, .$am, .$mpg), foo)}
```

In conclusion, it is not enough to have an object on the LHS of a pipe for R to magically apply it at the right places of the RHS (but I think your confusion might come from the case of `dplyr` functions (see below)). By default, it is used as the first argument of the function on the RHS (and in that case, you don't need any dot). For other placements, you do need a dot at each place where the LHS is needed. And in the case of nested functions (as you have here), you also need to enclose the RHS in curly braces or R will pass the LHS as the first argument of your outer-most RHS function.

---

Now, to your `mutate()` example:

```
ds_mt %>% 
  mutate(
    new_var = pmap(
      .l = list(model, am, mpg),
      .f = foo
    )
  )
```

This one works because, with newer versions of `dplyr`, the data frame and dollar sign are not necessary anymore when calling variables inside the `mutate()` function. So here, R does not wonder what `model` is because you are in a "mutate framework", so to speak, and R understands `model` as meaning `.$model` or `ds_mt$model`. So here again, this has nothing to do with `pmap()` or `pwalk()` but is a particularity of the `dplyr` functions (it would be the same with `summarise()`). I guess this shortcut of notation that `dplyr` functions allow is what lead you to some confusions.

---

Finally, what you call "explicit pair mapping" has no effect. Since you defined your function `foo()` as accepting 3 arguments, as long as you keep the arguments in the right order,

```
foo(model = model, am = am, mpg = mpg)
```

and

```
foo(model, am, mpg)
```

are exactly the same. If you swap the arguments around however, you do need to be explicit. For instance:

```
foo(am = am, model = model, mpg = mpg)
```